# How to remove duplicate lists in a list of list?

Tags: python

I want to remove all duplicates list from a list of list.

So I have a list of lists like this.

```
a = [[1,2],[1,2],[3,4,5],[3,4,5],[3,4,5]]
```

I want to have:

```
b = [[1,2],[3,4,5]]
```

I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You could use a set:

```
b_set = set(map(tuple,a))  #need to convert the inner lists to tuples so they are hashable
b = list(map(list,b_set)) #Now convert tuples back into lists (maybe unnecessary?)
```

Or, if you prefer list comprehensions/generators:

```
b_set = set(tuple(x) for x in a)
b = [ list(x) for x in b_set ]
```

Finally, if order is important, you can always sort b:

```
b.sort(key = lambda x: a.index(x) )
```

Comment: If you want something to be unique, a set is the way to go. :)

Comment: `lambda x: a.index(x)` could be just `a.index`

Comment: `b = map(list,b_set)` will return a map of lists, if you want it back to the original list of lists you'll want to instead do `b = list(map(list,b_set))`

Answer (score 15):

See mgilson's answer if the order of the lists is not important. If you want to retain the order, do something like:

```
b = list()
for sublist in a:
    if sublist not in b:
        b.append(sublist)
```

This will keep the order in the original list. However, it is slower and more verbose than using sets.

Comment: Thank you too, your method is interesting, but I don't need to keep the order.

Comment: Just note that this method will treat [1,2] and [2,1] as different, though it works for this example.

Comment: This method is slow. Avoid using append