# Generating a list of repetitions regardless of the order

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation, combinatorics

I want to generate combinations that associate indices in a list with "slots". For instance,`(0, 0, 1)` means that 0 and 1 belong to the same slot while 2 belongs to an other. `(0, 1, 1, 1)` means that 1, 2, 3 belong to the same slot while 0 is by itself. In this example, 0 and 1 are just ways of identifying these slots but do not carry information for my usage.

Consequently, `(0, 0, 0)` is absolutely identical to `(1, 1, 1)` for my purposes, and `(0, 0, 1)` is equivalent to `(1, 1, 0)`.

The classical cartesian product generates a lot of these repetitions I'd like to get rid of.

This is what I obtain with `itertools.product` :

```
>>> LEN, SIZE = (3,1)
>>> list(itertools.product(range(SIZE+1), repeat=LEN))
>>>
[(0, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 1),
(0, 1, 0),
(0, 1, 1),
(1, 0, 0),
(1, 0, 1),
(1, 1, 0),
(1, 1, 1)]
```

And this is what I'd like to get:

```
>>> [(0, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 1),
(0, 1, 0),
(0, 1, 1)]
```

It is easy with small lists but I don't quite see how to do this with bigger sets. Do you have a suggestion?

If it's unclear, please tell me so that I can clarify my question. Thank you!

**Edit**: based on Sneftel's answer, this function seems to work, but I don't know if it actually yields all the results:

```
def test():
    for p in product(range(2), repeat=3):
        j=-1
        good = True
        for k in p:
            if k> j and (k-j) > 1:
                good = False
            elif k >j:
                j = k
        if good:
            yield p
```

Comment: What's the purpose for this? Do you work with all the possibilities or do you just pick some of them? Are there always two "buckets" or do you sometimes have more?

Comment: I'm actually counting the incompatibilities between items (the indices) and I want to find out how to spread them in a limited amount of buckets to minimize this quantity. To do that, I'm enumerating all the different distributions and then I compute the number of incompatibilities (with a preferences list), but I don't care if 1, 2 and 3 are in a bucket A or in a bucket B. I only need to know whether are not they are in the same.
In my real life problem, I have 5 buckets and 12 items, that's why I really need to limit the enumeration of the cartesian product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by making the following observations:

1. The first element of each combination must be 0.
2. The second element must be 0 or 1.
3. The third element must be 0, 1 or 2, but *it can only be 2 if the second element was 1*.

These observations suggest the following algorithm:

```
def assignments(n, m, used=0):
    """Generate assignments of `n` items to `m` indistinguishable
    buckets, where `used` buckets have been used so far.

        >>> list(assignments(3, 1))
        [(0, 0, 0)]
        >>> list(assignments(3, 2))
        [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1)]
        >>> list(assignments(3, 3))
        [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2)]

    """
    if n == 0:
        yield ()
        return
    aa = list(assignments(n - 1, m, used))
    for first in range(used):
        for a in aa:
            yield (first,) + a
    if used < m:
        for a in assignments(n - 1, m, used + 1):
            yield (used,) + a
```

This handles your use case (12 items, 5 buckets) in a few seconds:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(lambda:list(assignments(12, 5)), number=1)
4.513746023178101
>>> sum(1 for _ in assignments(12, 5))
2079475
```

This is substantially faster than the function you give at the end of your answer (the one that calls `product` and then drops the invalid assignments) would be if it were modified to handle the (12, 5) use case:

```
>>> timeit(lambda:list(test(12, 5)), number=1)
540.693009853363
```

Answer (score 1):

Before checking for duplicates, you should harmonize the notation (assuming you don't want to set up some fancy AI): iterate through the lists and assign set-affiliation numbers for differing elements starting at 0, counting upwards. That is, you create a temporary dictionary per line that you are processing.

An exemplary output would be

```
(0,0,0) -> (0,0,0)
(0,1,0) -> (0,1,0)
```

but

```
(1,0,1) -> (0,1,0)
```

Removing the duplicates can then easily be performed as the problem is reduced to the problem of the solved question at [Python : How to remove duplicate lists in a list of list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198468/python-how-to-remove-duplicate-lists-in-a-list-of-list)

Answer (score 1):

If you only consider the elements of the cartesian product where the first occurrences of all indices are sorted and consecutive from zero, that should be sufficient. `itertools.combinations_with_replacement()` will eliminate those that are not sorted, so you'll only need to check that indices aren't being skipped.

Comment: I've managed to work out something following this idea, seems to work with my small example. I don't know if it actually yields all the possible solutions though...

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case you could simply take the first or the second half of the list of those items produced by a cartesian product.

```
import itertools

alphabet = '01' 
words3Lettered = [''.join(letter) for letter in itertools.product(alphabet,repeat=3)]
```

for n lettered words use `repeat=n`

words3Lettered looks like this:

```
['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```

next,

```
usefulWords = words3Lettered[:len(words3Lettered)/2]
```

which looks like this:

```
['000', '001', '010', '011']
```

you might be interested in the other half i.e. `words3Lettered[len(words3Lettered)/2:]` though the other half was supposed to "fold" onto the first half.

most probably you want to use the combination of letters in numeric form so...

```
indexes = [tuple(int(j) for j in word) for word in usefulWords]
```

which gives us:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1)]
```