# Remove duplicated lists in list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, set

I've seen some questions here very related but their answer doesn't work for me. I have a list of lists where some sublists are repeated but their elements may be disordered. For example

`g = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1], [1, 3, 2], [9, 0, 1], [4, 3, 2]]`

The output should be, naturally according to my question:

`g = [[1,2,3],[9,0,1],[4,3,2]]`

I've tried with `set` but only removes those lists that are equal (I thought It should work because sets are by definition without order). Other questions i had visited only has examples with lists exactly duplicated or repeated like this: [Python : How to remove duplicate lists in a list of list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198468/python-how-to-remove-duplicate-lists-in-a-list-of-list). For now order of output (for list and sublists) is not a problem.

Comment: Your answers are great! I am looking which answer behaves the best for larger lists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(ab)using side-effects version of a list comp:

```
seen = set()

[x for x in g if frozenset(x) not in seen and not seen.add(frozenset(x))]
Out[4]: [[1, 2, 3], [9, 0, 1], [4, 3, 2]]
```

For those (unlike myself) who don't like using side-effects in this manner:

```
res = []
seen = set()

for x in g:
    x_set = frozenset(x)
    if x_set not in seen:
        res.append(x)
        seen.add(x_set)
```

The reason that you add `frozenset`s to the set is that you can only add hashable objects to a `set`, and vanilla `set`s are not hashable.

Comment: Your answer was the fastest. And curiously it gave the output that wanted but I haven't asked for. It is twice faster than @jterrace answer. For a list of 4205 sublists, yours did it in 0.02 seconds.

Comment: @AlejandroSazo check please performance of my answer with generator expresion inside: `g = [list(x) for x in set(frozenset(i) for i in (set(i) for i in g))]` I am just curious about the benchmark, and will be happy to see it:)

Comment: @andi I will do it as soon as possible

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about the order for lists and sublists (and all items in sublists are unique):

```
result = set(map(frozenset, g))
```

If a sublist may have duplicates e.g., `[1, 2, 1, 3]` then you could use `tuple(sorted(sublist))` instead of `frozenset(sublist)` that removes duplicates from a sublist.

If you want to preserve the order of sublists:

```
def del_dups(seq, key=frozenset):
    seen = {}
    pos = 0
    for item in seq:
        if key(item) not in seen:
            seen[key(item)] = True
            seq[pos] = item
            pos += 1
    del seq[pos:]
```

Example:

```
del_dups(g, key=lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)))
```

See [In Python, what is the fastest algorithm for removing duplicates from a list so that all elements are unique *while preserving order*?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/89178/4279)

Comment: +1 Nice idea! Woul only add `[list(x) for x in set(map(frozenset, g))]` to produce output as the OP wanted.

Comment: @andi: I left the `result` as a set of `frozenset`s to stress that all sublists and all items in each sublist are unique and the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I would convert each element in the list to a frozenset (which is hashable), then create a set out of it to remove duplicates:

```
>>> g = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1], [1, 3, 2], [9, 0, 1], [4, 3, 2]]
>>> set(map(frozenset, g))
set([frozenset([0, 9, 1]), frozenset([1, 2, 3]), frozenset([2, 3, 4])])
```

If you need to convert the elements back to lists:

```
>>> map(list, set(map(frozenset, g)))
[[0, 9, 1], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: this answer seems to be very fast, and also returns tuples ordered. Only misses the list return :P

Comment: @AlejandroSazo Check out my updated answer. I think it's faster and simpler than your accepted one.

Comment: I will as soon as possible!

Answer (score 1):

What about using mentioned by roippi frozenset this way:

```
>>> g = [list(x) for x in set(frozenset(i) for i in [set(i) for i in g])]

[[0, 9, 1], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: If performance matters you can replace `list comprehension` with `generator expresion`. Just replace `[]` with `()` making it: `g = [list(x) for x in set(frozenset(i) for i in (set(i) for i in g))]` What is the difference you can read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension

Comment: Your first approach (list comprehension) uses 0.070491 seconds. Your approach with generator expression took 0.030556 seconds. The accepted answer time was 0.02 seconds :)