# Remove tuples that are duplicate combinations of lists in the list of these tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, duplicates, tuples

I have the list

```
a = [([4, 7, 9], [3], 5.5), ([2, 5, 8], [3], 5.5), ([3], [4, 7, 9], 5.5), ([3], [2, 5, 8], 5.5)]
```

and I am trying to remove duplicate tuples that have the same combination of lists.

For example, `([4, 7, 9], [3], 5.5)` and `([3], [4, 7, 9], 5.5)` are the same. So the output after removing the duplicate tuples will look something like:

```
a = [([4, 7, 9], [3], 5.5), ([2, 5, 8], [3], 5.5)]
```

with any order of the lists in the tuples allowed.

**Edit (based on @DYZ's feedback):** Fully flattened tuples are not allowed. For example, `(4,7,9,3,5.5)` is not allowed. The output should still be of the form: `([list 1], [list2], constant)`.

I tried to adapt a method that is related in [Remove duplicated lists in list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850602/remove-duplicated-lists-in-list-of-lists-in-python), but I have reached a mental deadlock..

Is it possible to modify the code further in the linked question, or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian what do you mean by that?

Comment: Are you allowed to have fully-flattened tuples in your result list? (With no sublists whatsoever.) E.g., `(4, 7, 9, 3, 5.5)`.

Comment: @DYZ If you mean (4,7,9,3,5.5) for e.g. then no, that is not allowed. the output should still be of the form `([list 1], [list2], constant)`

Comment: You may want to add this constraint to the question.

Comment: @DYZ Thanks for the feedback! I'll add it right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary for this job. Create an empty dictionary:

```
from itertools import chain
d = {}
```

Insert each tuple and its flattened form into the dictionary as the value and the key, respectively:

```
for t in a:
    # Flatten the tuple
    flat = chain.from_iterable(part if isinstance(part,list) else [part] 
                               for part in t)
    maps_to = frozenset(flat) # Sets cannot be used as keys
    d[maps_to] = t # Add it to the dict; the most recent addition "survives"

list(d.values())
#[([3], [4, 7, 9], 5.5), ([3], [2, 5, 8], 5.5)]
```

Comment: Thank you it works! The beauty of the dictionary.. One that I have not yet mastered in using :/

Answer (score 2):

Sort the elements of a by their length (setting the length of elements which aren't list as -1). Then find the indices of the unique elements of the resulting sort, and use those to index into the unsorted list.

```
asort = [sorted(aa, key= lambda x: len(x) if isinstance(x,list) else -1) for aa in a]
inds = [i for i,x in enumerate(asort) if asort.index(x)==i]
a = [a[i] for i in inds]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and help! It works fine for me too :)